# "Cannot create generic array of .." - how to create an Array of Map<String, Object>?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, hashmap

I would like to use simpleJdbcInsert class and executeBatch method

```
public int[] executeBatch(Map<String,Object>[] batch)
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsert.html

So I need to pass an array of `Map<String,Object>` as parameter. How to create such an array?
What I tried is

```
Map<String, Object>[] myArray = new HashMap<String, Object>[10]
```

It is error: Cannot create generic array of `Map<String, Object>`

A `List<Map<String, Object>>` would be easier, but I guess I need an array. So how to create an array of `Map<String, Object>` ?
Thanks

Comment: I would likely start with a List and [turn it into an array as needed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])), since I dislike dealing with Java arrays .. but this is still a valid question nevertheless.

Comment: @pst: Post that as an answer. I hate casting generic arrays (my last attempt at an answer was incorrect because I forgot how broken generics were).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Because of how generics in Java work, you cannot directly create an array of a generic type (such as `Map<String, Object>[]`).  Instead, you create an array of the raw type (`Map[]`) and cast it to `Map<String, Object>[]`.  This will cause an unavoidable (but suppressible) compiler warning.

This should work for what you need:

```
Map<String, Object>[] myArray = (Map<String, Object>[]) new Map[10];
```

You may want to annotate the method this occurs in with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, to prevent the warning from being shown.

Comment: when i use LinkedHashMap<String,String>map_array[] = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>[2]; , it also gives this error? Now i dont understand what is 'generic' here?

Comment: @Diffy The "generic" part is the type parameters `<String,String>`.  To remove the error (and replace it with a warning), use `LinkedHashMap<String, String>[] map_array = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) new LinkedHashMap[2];`

Comment: Yes, i got out of the error by using simply new LinkedHashMap[2], but it would have been generic if i would have used an Object datatype or "T" (generic  tmplate ). How come <String,String> is generic? I am specifying the proper datatype here

Comment: "Generic" in this case means "Type that has type parameters, or is defined by a type parameter". So `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` becomes `LinkedHashMap`, `T` becomes `Object` (normally), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can create generic array of map.

1. Create a list of maps.

   ```
   List<Map<String, ?>> myData = new ArrayList<Map<String, ?>>();
   ```
2. Initialize array.

   ```
   Map<String,?>[] myDataArray = new HashMap[myData.size()];
   ```
3. Populate data in array from list.

   ```
   myDataArray = myData.toArray(myDataArray);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have had some difficulty with this, but I have figured out a few things that I will share as simply as possible.

My experience with generics is limited to collections, so I use them in the class definitions, such as:

```
public class CircularArray<E> {
```

which contains the data member:

```
private E[] data;
```

But you can't make and array of type generic, so it has the method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private E[] newArray(int size)
{
    return (E[]) new Object[size];  //Create an array of Objects then cast it as E[]
}
```

In the constructor:

```
data = newArray(INITIAL_CAPACITY);  //Done for reusability
```

This works for generic generics, but I needed a list that could be sorted: a list of Comparables.

```
public class SortedCircularArray<E extends Comparable<E>> { 
//any E that implements Comparable or extends a Comparable class
```

which contains the data member:

```
private E[] data;
```

But our new class throws java.lang.ClassCastException:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private E[] newArray(int size)
{
    //Old: return (E[]) new Object[size];  //Create an array of Objects then cast it as E[]
    return (E[]) new Comparable[size];  //A comparable is an object, but the converse may not be
}
```

In the constructor everything is the same:

```
data = newArray(INITIAL_CAPACITY);  //Done for reusability
```

I hope this helps and I hope our more experienced users will correct me if I've made mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

From [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays) [*sic*]:

> You cannot create arrays of parameterized types. For example, the following code does not compile:
>
> ```
> List<Integer>[] arrayOfLists = new List<Integer>[2];  // compile-time error
> ```
>
> The following code illustrates what happens when different types are inserted into an array:
>
> ```
> Object[] strings = new String[2];
> strings[0] = "hi";   // OK
> strings[1] = 100;    // An ArrayStoreException is thrown.
> ```
>
> If you try the same thing with a generic list, there would be a problem:
>
> ```
> Object[] stringLists = new List<String>[];  // compiler error, but pretend it's allowed
> stringLists[0] = new ArrayList<String>();   // OK
> stringLists[1] = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // An ArrayStoreException should be thrown,
>                                             // but the runtime can't detect it.
> ```
>
> If arrays of parameterized lists were allowed, the previous code would fail to throw the desired ArrayStoreException.

To me, it sounds very weak. I think that any programmer with a sufficient understanding of generics, would be perfectly fine, and even expect, that the ArrayStoredException is not thrown in such case.

Even more, most programmers will simply do:

```
List<Integer> arrayOfLists = (List<Integer>) new List[2];
```

which will put them in exactly the same risk of ArrayStoreException not thrown.

Answer (score 0):

As far my knowledge

Frist try to create an array of java.lang.Object and then cast to Generic type T

Example:

```
class Example<DataType>{
    public DataType array = (DataType[]) new Object[5] ; 
}
```

In this way, you can create an array of generic datatype

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Map<String,?>[] newArray(int n) {
  return new Map[n];
}
```

using with a `Stream` of `Map<String,?>`:

```
  sql.executeBatch(myStream.toArray(this::newArray));
```

using with a `List` of `Map<String,?>`:

```
  sql.executeBatch(myList.toArray(newArray(0));
```

NOTE: the SuppressWarnings trick is actively used in JDK src - https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk14/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L395:L404

Credits to: @JonathanCallen