# Casting from raw type to generic type

Tags: java, arrays, generics

In the below syntax from `java.util.HashMap`, Generic type parameters are used for type casting after instantiating a raw type array,

`Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];`

Similar code does not compile [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/blob/master/JavaCode/src/StaticMemberClasses/NestedInterfaceInInterface.java) with similar syntax(as shown below), giving **error**: `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Node[] to Node<K,V>[]`

```
public class NestedInterfaceInInterface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[10];
        //Node<String,String>[] newTab = (Node<String,String>[])new Node[10];  // this works


    }
}
```

1) How do I resolve this error ?

2) How syntax `Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[10];` different from `Node<String,String>[] newTab = (Node<String,String>[])new Node[10];`?

Comment: You cannot instantiate generic array types. They therefore use the raw type and cast it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917375/cannot-create-generic-array-of-how-to-create-an-array-of-mapstring-obje) question.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Do you think this is duplicate question?

Comment: @bcsb1001 please read the question again

Comment: @overexchange Read the accepted answer to that question. It answers yours, too. That is the meaning of a duplicate on SO, therefore this is a duplicate. It doesn't have to be verbatim the same question.

Comment: `Node` is a generic class which declares two type variables, `K` and `V`. In your example, no such types exist.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can u answer my first question?

Comment: The _How do I resolve this error ?_ question? Do you know what type arguments are in generics? `String` is a type name that is in scope. `K` and `V` are not, in your example.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that [you can't create an array of a generic type in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java) so you are forced to cast a raw type array of `Node[]` to a `Node<K,V>[]` by hand.

The operation is called [type conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) and it is used in multiple occasions. In this circumstance you are doing an unsafe downcast which will yield a warning

> Type Safety: unchecked cast from `Node[]` to `Node<K,V>[]`

But you can suppress it in case. Mind that there is no way to prevent this warning and you could consider using a `List<Node<K,V>>` which wouldn't have such problems.

Comment: Firstly, why do we need `static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> { }`? when we want to create raw type array `new Node[newCap]`. Can it be `static class Node implements Map.Entry{}`?

Comment: You don't want a raw type array, you want a generic type array but you can't create it directly.

Comment: What is the difference between `Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];` **and** `Node<String,String>[] newTab = new Node<String, String>[newCap];`?

Comment: The difference is that the latter won't compile because __you can't create an array of generic objects__ as stated in my answer.

Comment: As you said: "there is no way to prevent this warning", but how is this syntax working in `java.util.HashMap`?`Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why generic arrays are not allowed is due to Java's type erasure. Even `Collections` such as `List<T>` merely casts between `Object` and `T` when objects are accessed. The most typesafe way of viewing generics is using `Collections.checkedCollection` which takes `Collection<E>` and `Class<E>` and checks the type at runtime, preventing the compiler-issued warnings at compile time.

Comment: the question is, line `Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];` works in `java.util.HashMap` but like  `Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[10];` does not work in this [example](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/blob/master/JavaCode/src/StaticMemberClasses/NestedInterfaceInInterface.java). why?

Comment: @overexchange Because you haven't specified the type parameters `K,V` in the class declaration? Change it to `public class NestedInterfaceInInterface<K,V>`.

Comment: That won't work either. They're attempting the code in a `static` method. Make the method generic or introduce the type parameters some other way.