# Initialize Static Array of Map in Java

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, static, hashmap

Im having problems when trying to initialize the variable:

```
Map<Sentence, Float>[] vectorValueSentences; // this is ok

/* but this is not */ vectorValueSentences = new HashMap<Sentence, Float>()[100];
```

I search on what to do but i didnt find any. I read that the object to be initialize has to be static but i dont find a way to declare the Map static.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you include a fuller snippet? It's hard to understand without some more context.

Comment: If `vectorValuesSentences` is not declared before calling the line `vectorValueSentences = new HashMap<Sentence, Float>()[100];`, obviously its wrong

Comment: Because of how generics in Java work, you cannot directly create an array of a generic type (such as Map<Object, Object>[]). Or You are trying to do something else? More in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917375/cannot-create-generic-array-of-how-to-create-an-array-of-mapstring-obje

Comment: You should consider using a List of Maps. List<Map<Sentence, Float>> vectorValueSentences = new ArrayList<Map<Sentence, Float>>();

Comment: Thank you guys! it was my first question here and solve it so quickly. Hope i can help in this community from now on

Answer (score 1):

```
    HashMap<Sentence, Float>[] vectorValueSentences = new HashMap[100];
```

Comment: Wooooooow, thank you! I can believe it was so simple and yet couldn't find it anywhere. Deepak Marathe, you are great :)